# Include task when compared version is lower

Tags: ansible

I'd like to install docker when version is lower than *19.03.2*.

```
---
- include_tasks: get_version.yml

- include_tasks: install.yml
  when: (docker_version | int) is version('19.03.2', '<=')
```

**get_version.yml**

```
---
- name: Get docker version
  shell: docker --version
  register: results

- name: Extract docker version
  set_fact:
    docker_version: "{{ results.stdout | regex_search('^.*version\\s([0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}),.+$','\\1') }}"

- name: Show docker version
  debug: var=docker_version
```

What's the right condition? the current code always include `install.yml`. The current `docker_version` i am getting is 1.13.1

Comment: Can you paste the output of docker_version

Comment: extracted 1.13.1 from my regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example the tasks below

```
  tasks:
    - command: docker --version
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        docker_version: "{{ result.stdout.split(' ')[2].split('-')[0] }}"
    - debug:
        var: docker_version
    - debug:
        msg: Install docker
      when: docker_version is version('19.03.2', '<=')
```

give

```
"docker_version": "18.06.1"

"msg": "Install docker"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try without converting to int?

```
- include_tasks: install.yml
  when: docker_version is version('19.03.2', '<=')
```

Also in your code the compared version is lower, so I guess the install.yml playbook should be called.